# Autoupdate private application for iOS 7

Tags: ios, app-store, private, auto-update

My application needs to be updated automatically, without user confirmation. Any way to achieve this except AppStore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't update your app without user interaction. You have to use the App Store's update mechanism.

Apples App Store Review Guidelines say:

> 2.7 Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected